# Wrong daylight saving date when using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime?

Tags: c#, .net, time, timezone, dst

On November 6th, 2011, at 2 AM (EST, e.g. in New York), it was 3 AM according to the [daylight saving time schedule](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=179&year=2011).

Does someone know why the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` function from the .NET framework returns the following:

```
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var f = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTimeOffset(2012, 11, 3, 11, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero), tzi).ToString(f);
"2012/11/03 07:00:00"
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTimeOffset(2012, 11, 4, 11, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero), tzi).ToString(f);
"2012/11/04 06:00:00"
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTimeOffset(2012, 11, 6, 11, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero), tzi).ToString(f);
"2012/11/06 06:00:00"
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTimeOffset(2012, 11, 7, 11, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero), tzi).ToString(f);
"2012/11/07 06:00:00"
```

It seems as if the time change occurred on the 4th of November, which makes no sense as it occurred on the 6th.

**Edit:** wow, this one is on me. I used 2012 instead of 2011 in my code.

Comment: Your code would be a *lot* easier to read if we didn't have to scroll across to get at it... (And having a variable called "zone" rather than calling FindSystemTimeZoneById in each call would help, too...)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your description:

> On November 6th, **2011**

Now look at your code:

```
new DateTimeOffset(2012, 11, 3, 11, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero)
```

I think we've found the problem.

Looking at the [daylight saving time schedule for 2012](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=179&year=2012) shows the change occurring on November 4th 2012, just as .NET says.

Of course, I'd still argue that the code would be clearer in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), but I'm biased :)

Comment: Wow. I think the bug was in my head. I need to look for some Baygon. Or Noda.

Comment: @ErwinMayer: Up to you. I'm not going to mind much either way.

Comment: I submitted a request to delete it as I cannot do it myself yet. I do not mind if it stays (even though it may confuse some people looking for a similar issue) so if the moderator prefers to keep it that is fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet I ask a Related question, can you please check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506631/convert-calendars-to-each-other-use-nodatime-library