# Convert calendars to each other Use NodaTime library

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar, nodatime

I use [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) to handle `DateTime` issues, I read almost all of the [documents](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/userguide/index.html) but I have some problem to convert calendars to each other,

1. First, how many calendars are supported by Noda?

   As `CalendarSystem` says there is just 4 calendars:

   a)CopticCalendar / b)GregorianCalendar / c)IslamicCalendar / d)JulianCalendar

   so how about other calendar systems?
2. I use [Persian Calendar aka Jalali Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_Calendar), So is there any way to use this calendar in NodaTime? And how Convert it to Gregorian Calendar?
3. The final goal for me is to convert both Time(in special Zone) and Date to UTC Time Zone And Georgian Calendar. For example **Now**(`yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss`) in `Asia/Tehran` time Zone And Persian Calendar is: (1391/06/30 - 10:01:15) and **Now** in Georgian Calendar and UTC is (2012/09/20 - 05:01:15), so what is your suggestion? The time individually not matter at all, but the Date, I don't have any idea about it(In NodaTime), and is there any way to convert both of these in one process or method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, currently those are the only calendar systems we support.
2. No, we don't have any support for the Persian Calendar at the moment. You can file a feature request, but we're more likely to be interested in getting 1.0 out of the door to start with, I'm afraid.
3. It's not clear what you mean by "special zone" - but it sounds like again, you'd need the Persian calendar for this to really work. If .NET supports the Persian calendar, you could parse it to a `DateTime` first, and then convert that to a Noda Time type... I'm sorry that we don't support the Persian calendar at the moment, and I'd *like* to be able to support the BCL calendars via wrapping types (as we do for `TimeZoneInfo`) but that won't be any time soon, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others searching for similar keywords, support for Persian calendar has been added (I'm currently using v1.3).

Some calendars have more settings, so this example is simplified:

```
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var nodaNow = new NodaTime.LocalDate(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);
    var cal = nodaNow.WithCalendar(CalendarSystem.GetPersianCalendar());

    Console.WriteLine(cal.ToString());
```